# Google cloud dataflow restapi always returns 403-SERVICE_DISABLED

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-java-client

I have this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-dataflow</artifactId>
    <version>v1b3-rev20221025-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here i am building the dataflow:

```
private fun dataflow(): Dataflow = Dataflow.Builder(
    "My credentials",
    ...,
    ...
).build()
```

When i try to invoke some of the dataflow methods it always returns 403-SERVICE_DISABLED although i have pipelines with jobs in my project.

EX:

```
dataflow().projects().jobs().list("myProjectId").execute()
```

I tried changing the dependency version, calling different methods but the result is the same.
I have dependencies for other resources and they works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that the service account which i provide as ServiceAccountCredential was in another project where this API was not enabled. So the API have to be enabled in the project where service account is located and in the project, where my resources are located.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the [Google apis java client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client) when you should be using the [google cloud java client libary](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java).

You should consult the documentation here [google-cloud-dataflow overview (0.10.0)](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/overview)

```
 // This snippet has been automatically generated and should be regarded as a code template only.
 // It will require modifications to work:
 // - It may require correct/in-range values for request initialization.
 // - It may require specifying regional endpoints when creating the service client as shown in
 // https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/setup#configure_endpoints_for_the_client_library
 try (JobsV1Beta3Client jobsV1Beta3Client = JobsV1Beta3Client.create()) {
   CreateJobRequest request =
       CreateJobRequest.newBuilder()
           .setProjectId("projectId-894832108")
           .setJob(Job.newBuilder().build())
           .setView(JobView.forNumber(0))
           .setReplaceJobId("replaceJobId441554788")
           .setLocation("location1901043637")
           .build();
   Job response = jobsV1Beta3Client.createJob(request);
 }
```

Comment: I tried with this lib and getting this error: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Dataflow API has not been used in project "MyProjectId"before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dataflow.googleapis.com/overview?project="MyProjectId" then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Comment: you need to enable this API in your project before you can use it follow the Link in the error message

Comment: The problem is that the api is enabled in this project and i have pipelines and jobs in it. The error which google returns does not correspond with the api state.

Comment: Then you are not using the project id you think you are using.  The error message says its not enabled its not enabled.

Comment: The projectId is correct. I faced issues with google cloud restapi and sometimes the response which they provide is different than the real problem.